# Product Custom Fields with HTML and JS

Tags: custom-field, html-editor

I have a custom textarea filed for the product page.

```
woocommerce_wp_textarea_input(
    array(
        'id' => '_custom_product_calc',
        'label' => __('Test', 'woocommerce')
    )
);

$woocommerce_custom_product_calc = $_POST['_custom_product_calc'];
if (!empty($woocommerce_custom_product_calc))
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_custom_product_calc', esc_html($woocommerce_custom_product_calc));
```

I need to use this field for insert some HTML code with JS. But, as you can see, the result is not what I've expected.

[image]

How can I change this? Or, maybe you know a better way to add a tab with  HTML and JS for a product page? Clone Short description, for example?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't use WooCommerce so I have a bad understanding of the whole context. With that said, if you change your `esc_html` to [`wp_kses`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses/) and supply it with an array of legal tags and their allowed attributes, you might get what you need. Though this looks like it's escaping when *saving* instead of *outputting*, which seems like the wrong way to go about this.